Spamhaus throttling my dns queries. Do I need to run my own dns server?
I am hosted on vultr and I am using their local DNS server in /etc/resolv file. Recently I started noticing the following responses from their DNS based block list zen.spamhaus.org:
451 Error: open resolver
I did a fair bit of research and my understanding is that the vultr DNS server is sending too many queries to zen. spamhaus.org
My email server is very small and I am surely not causing this, there must be many customers using the same vultr DNS server and they all make the query volume big forcing spamhaus to throttle  the queries. I have no control over that so I am not sure how to proceed with this, should I launch my own local DNS server so that spamhaus would see me as a separate "entity" with my small queries volume? Please advise

Yes, you need to run your own local DNS server like unbound.

Replace Google’s public resolver with the DNS server of your provider in this answer of mine to know why you should run your own resolver rather use Vultr dns servers for your DNSBL lookups
